# How to put link in submit-button, using Clojure

Tags: forms, post, clojure, get, submit-button

I've been working on a Clojure project for some time and was wondering how to navigate user from one page to another after clicking the submit-button.
Code goes like this:

```
(defn view-film-input [] 
 (view-layout 
   [:body {:style "background-color: #F2FB78"}
   [:h2 "Add new film"] 
   (form-to [:post "/addfilm" ]

  (label "movname" "Film title: ")
  (text-field  :txtname) [:br] 

  (label "prname" "Producer name: ")
  (text-field  :txtprname) [:br] 
  (label "location" "File location: ")
  (text-field :txtlocation)[:br]

  (label "duration" "Duration(minutes): ")
  (text-field  :txtduration)[:br]
  (submit-button "Save"))]))
```

Now, this works but I would like to navigate user to same "Add new film" page, or refresh the form after clicking "Save" button, instead it shows just a blank page.

This is the GET\POST part:

```
 (GET "/addfilm" [] (view-film-input))
 (POST "/addfilm" [txtname txtprname txtlocation txtduration]
    (insert-flick txtname txtprname txtlocation txtduration 90) )
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume this is compojure. Your views need to return a response. What does `insert-flick` return?

Comment: It's defined in another class, which manages database. Adds new film to the table, using txtname, txtprname, txtlocation and txtduration as attributes

Answer (score 2):

You have two possibilities here.

**Redirect the User**

Using the `Location` header of a HTTP 302 (or 303) response you can specify a path the user's browser should display instead of the current one:

```
(POST "/addfilm" [...]
  ...
  {:status 302
   :headers {"Location" "/addfilm"}})
```

There are also two functions in `ring.util.response` that would generate the responses for you:  [`redirect`](http://ring-clojure.github.io/ring/ring.util.response.html#var-redirect) and [`redirect-after-post`](http://ring-clojure.github.io/ring/ring.util.response.html#var-redirect-after-post) - with the latter being more applicable to your use case.

*EDIT:* [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6788439/1916789) elaborates on why 303 would be the status code to send after POST, specifically:

> If you use 302, you're risking that UA will re-send POST to the new URL instead of switching to GET.

**Render the same Page again**

Simpler and prompting less I/O, but imposing some duplication would be to render the same view again, i.e.:

```
(POST "/addfilm" [...]
  ...
  (view-film-input))
```

This seems less maintainable to me but it is probably the shortest path to solving your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, really appreciate the fast response