# Devise routing: is there a way to remove a route from Rails.application.routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes

`devise_for` creates routes including a DELETE route, which we want to remove, and `devise_for` doesn't support an `:except` or `:only` option.

How can I remove a route from `Rails.application.routes`?  Either in the `draw` block, or afterward?

---

Here are details of a bug, which was the reason we needed to remove the route.

- we were issuing a DELETE request to a custom UJS controller action
- in the controller action we were removing what we wanted to, then doing a 302 redirect.  This was a bad idea, and we have since corrected it by returning some JSON instead.
- some clients, upon receiving the 302 would issue a new DELETE request to the redirect, which routes to a Devise delete route!  Thereby inadvertantly deleting the person! Yikes. We were assuming this would be a GET.   Bad assumption.

This bug has been fixed, but i would like to remove the route nonetheless.

---

Here is what I did in the end, which was suggested by the bounty-winner in his quote from Jose´ Valim:

In `config/routes.rb`, I added this above the `devise_for` call, which sets up the rest of my `'people'` routes:

```
delete '/person', :to => 'people#destroy'
```

Then in my existing `people_controller.rb`, I added a no-op method:

```
def destroy
  render :nothing => true
end
```

I'm still a little irked that there isn't a simple way to just remove the route from the RouteSet.  Also, the `delete` route still exists for the devise controller, but it won't get called because rails looks for the first match in `config/routes.rb` and returns it.

Comment: Nice questions. And would be nice to know what that IE8 bug is!

Comment: I added an edit with the story of our bug.  Not sure the bug is exclusive to IE8, see this answer on 302s: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764297/difference-between-http-redirect-codes.

Comment: For posterity I've appended [another solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986861/rails-3-routing-is-there-a-way-to-remove-a-route-from-rails-application-routes/7035415#7035415) to my answer.

Comment: instead of render you can use 'redirect_to root_path'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is what Jose Valim (the author of devise) [has to say on the subject](http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_thread/thread/50e36a243b4b9c98):

> There is no way to remove routes individually. Or you use :skip to 
>   remove all and draw the ones you need manually or you overwrite this 
>   routes by defining a route to the same path first in your config/ 
>   routes.rb

So the short answer to your question is no, you can't delete that one route. You can of course try doing things like patching the devise_for method, but that would be a somewhat involved undertaking (a day or several worth of effort). I'd just use the :skip option, then implement the routes you do want for that controller and leave off the one that you don't.

Comment: I'm awarding you the bounty for the quote from José Valim, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Yes, kinda. You can completely overwrite devise controllers used and write your own (inheriting Devise's if needed). [This wiki page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes) can serve as guideline.

### Edit

Why I have said kinda :)

Overriding sessions using:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => 'custom_devise/sessions'}, :skip => [:sessions] do
  get 'sign_in' => 'custom_devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
  post 'sign_in' => 'custom_devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
end
```

will give you only two routes [:get, :post], but not :destroy

```
new_user_session GET  /sign_in(.:format) {:controller=>"custom_devise/sessions", :action=>"new"}
user_session POST /sign_in(.:format) {:controller=>"custom_devise/sessions", :action=>"create"}
```

So, effectively, you skip destroy/delete route. Now in controller you can go:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end

end
```

You can now repeat the process for registrations, passwords and unlocks.

### Second Edit

Ah, yes there is another, simpler way. You can manually create routes ([documentation](http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper)) using devise_scope also known as "as" without overriding:

```
as :user do
  get  "sign_in", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
  post "sign_in", :to => "devise/sessions#create"
  ...
end
```

Gives:

```
sign_in GET  /sign_in(.:format) {:controller=>"devise/sessions", :action=>"new"}
        POST /sign_in(.:format) {:controller=>"devise/sessions", :action=>"create"}
```

### Third Edit

Also, you could overwrite [part of Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb) in charge of creating these routes, (only to be used in applications that will have no devise "destroy" route whatsoever), by creating an initializer:

```
module ActionDispatch::Routing
  extend ActionDispatch::Routing
  class Mapper

    protected
      def devise_session(mapping, controllers) #:nodoc:
        resource :session, :only => [], :controller => controllers[:sessions], :path => "" do
          get   :new,     :path => mapping.path_names[:sign_in],  :as => "new"
          post  :create,  :path => mapping.path_names[:sign_in]
        end
      end

      def devise_registration(mapping, controllers) #:nodoc:
        path_names = {
          :new => mapping.path_names[:sign_up],
          :cancel => mapping.path_names[:cancel]
        }

        resource :registration, :only => [:new, :create, :edit, :update], :path => mapping.path_names[:registration],
                 :path_names => path_names, :controller => controllers[:registrations] do
          get :cancel
        end
      end
  end
end
```

Note that this fix removes *all destroy* routes used in Devise (there are only two in "sessions" and "registrations") and is a fix only for this specific case.

### In addition

You could also add :except option to routes. In order to do it, you must add `devise_for` method ([copy it from original](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb) and modify to suit your wishes) to Mapper class so it sends [:except] member of options to above-mentioned (in code) private methods.. Then you should modify those to add routes based on conditions.

Fastest, dirty way, would be to add @scope[:except] = options[:except] and then to modify private methods so that except hash (if you decide to have fine grained route control like: `:except => {:sessions => [:destroy]}`, thus making `:skip` obsolete) or array (if you want to remove this specific action from all routes, like: `:except => [:destroy]`) is checked before adding route.

Anyway, there are plenty ways to achieve what you need. It's up to you to pick the one you think is best suited.

Comment: I know i can redirect a route to a new controller, but i'd like to remove the route altogether.

Comment: Please see edit. I hope that is what you want. You can't just remove route but you can override devise routes this way leaving it out.

Comment: I have 13 person routes that i would have to specify, just to remove one!  I suppose i could just specify a `match` for the one route and then reroute it to no_op controller action.  But thats a horrible hack, seems like i should be able to specify one route to remove from the RouteSet object.

Comment: Well, other than forking devise, making necessary changes, and pushing back, or asking for this feature hoping someone will write it, this is, as far as I know, the only way.

Comment: Added another answer/option above

Answer (score 8):

Actually `devise_for` does support `:skip` and `:only`, for example ([docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb#L98)):

```
devise_for :user, :skip => :registration
```

This will skip all the registration controller's routes, rather than one specifically. You could then implement the routes you need. This seems cleaner than removing the route after the fact.

**UPDATE:**

Another possible solution is to use Rails' [advanced constraints](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints) feature to block the unwanted route completely:

```
# config/routes.rb
constraints lambda {|req| req.url =~ /users/ && req.delete? ? false : true} do
  devise_for :users
end
```

Here is a post on using [lambdas for route constraints](http://intridea.com/2011/2/21/use-lambdas-for-rails3-route-constraints?blog=company). The request object is explained [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object). This might be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 2):

I found a simple solution with Devise 4.2.0 and Rails 5.0.1. I *think* this will work with Rails 4, and I'm uncertain about older versions of Devise.

Create an initializer overriding the `devise_*` route helpers. Examples methods are `devise_session`, `devise_password`, `devise_confirmation`, `devise_unlock`, and `devise_registration`. Check out the [source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb).

Ensure the initializer is loaded after the Devise initializer by giving the filename a larger alphanumeric value.

For example, Devise creates a :confirmation route with the `:new`, `:create`, and `:show` actions. I only want the `:create` action.

```ruby
# config/initializers/devise_harden.rb
module ActionDispatch::Routing
  class Mapper

    # Override devise's confirmation route setup, as we want to limit it to :create
    def devise_confirmation(mapping, controllers)
      resource :confirmation, only: [:create],
               path: mapping.path_names[:confirmation], controller: controllers[:confirmations]
    end
  end
end
```

Now `POST /auth/confirmation` is the only route setup for confirmation.

Comment: Looks like @Krule already had this in his Third Edit. I found this easy and following Rails convention.