# Changing devise user_registration_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

From my `rake routes`:

```
     user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
 new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
```

So when I click submit button in registration form it moves me to `/users`.

How can I change it so `user_registration POST` would be `/users/sign_up(.:format)` ?
I tried something like this:

```
  devise_for :users

  as :user do
    post 'sign_up' => 'devise/registrations#create', as: 'user_registration'
  end
```

But there is conflict as `user_registration` prefix is already generated by `devise_for`

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, you need to stop generating default registrations#create action. Unfortunately there is no easy way to do so (or customize it). The best approach I can find is to skip generating registration routes for users and define all of them later with devise_scope method:

```
devise_for :users, skip: :registration
devise_scope :user do
  resource :registration, :as => :user_registration, :only => [ :new, :edit, :update, :destroy ], :path=> "/users", :path_names=> { :new =>"sign_up" }, :controller=>"devise/registrations"  do
    get :cancel
    post :sign_up, action: :create, as: ''
  end
end
```

This could be probably cleaned up a bit but it generates what you expect:

```
    user_registration POST   /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#create
new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
```

P.S. related problem is discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986861/rails-3-routing-is-there-a-way-to-remove-a-route-from-rails-application-routes)