# How to skip only new_registrations_path in devise rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I want to skip new_registrations_path because I do not want that user signup itself. Admin can add it.

To skip this I do that

```
devise_for :advertisers, :skip => :registrations
```

But issue is that edit_registration_path also skip with it. How I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Devise routing: is there a way to remove a route from Rails.application.routes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986861/devise-routing-is-there-a-way-to-remove-a-route-from-rails-application-routes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
devise_for :advertisers, :skip => [:registrations]

 as :advertiser do
   get "/advertisers/edit" => "devise/registrations#edit", :as => :edit_advertisers_registration 
   put "/advertisers" => "devise/registrations#update", :as => :advertisers_registration
 end
```

Hope this will help you .