# How long is a 302 redirect saved in browser?

Tags: redirect, browser, browser-cache, cache-control, http-status-code-302

Due to a misconfiguration of our webserver the main domain sent a 302 redirect to a new location. We fixed that issue. When emptying the browser cache everything works fine now.

For the "normal" client who does not empty his cache: How long is the 302 redirect kept in the browser?

I'm looking for **specific cache times** (if any) for each of the major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, Edge, IE 12) under default settings.

Comment: [Redirect caching deep dive](https://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/07/23/redirect-caching-deep-dive/) article by Steve Souders contains a link to a relevant web tests.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It shouldn't be cached at all unless there's also a `Cache-Control` or `Expires` header returned by the web server. According to [RFC 2616, section 10.3.3 302 Found](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3)

> The requested resource resides temporarily under a different URI. Since the redirection might be altered on occasion, the client SHOULD continue to use the Request-URI for future requests. This response is only cacheable if indicated by a Cache-Control or Expires header field.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like my default test browser (Chrome) just fooled me about this: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=103458 (Chrome caches, others not)

Comment: @OleAlbers I was about to edit my answer with a note (before my internet died) that although the RFC says that clients **SHOULD** continue to use the original URI, that it doesn't mean all browsers will, it's going to need to be taken as a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 22):

The standard referenced by Jon Lin here uses "SHOULD", which is [not as strong as "MUST"](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) in RFC lingo. This is not just a theoretical distiction; Cloudflare, for example, [*does* cache redirects](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168326-Are-301-and-302-redirects-cached-by-CloudFlare-):

> If no cache headers are provided (no Cache-Control or Expires) and the
>   url is cacheable (.jpg, .css, .js etc.) then CloudFlare caches both
>   301 and 302s. We cache 301 for a couple of hours and 302s for a
>   shorter period of time (~20 minutes).

So you should either make sure you can handle it or use explicit headers (e.g. `Cache-Control: private, no-cache`) to direct browsers and intermediates against caching it.

Comment: Yup, this was the issue for me - not specifying `Cache-Control` was causing the cached redirect. Can take a look at this thread for a more comprehensive look at specifying no-cache headers though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-to-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers

Answer (score 10):

Using Steve Sounder's [Redirect Caching Tests tool](http://stevesouders.com/tests/redirects/index.php) (thanks @LeonidVasilev), it seems that the results may not be what are expected. With no expires headers or cookies, the results were as follows:

**Chrome 71**: Not Cached ✔
**Firefox 64**: Cached ✕
**Safari 12**: Cached ✕

So despite what [RFC 2616, section 10.3.3 302 Found](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3) states, not all browsers follow these guidelines or what might be considered expected behaviour :(

Answer (score 3):

Add the

```
Cache-Control: no-store
```

header to the response and it won't be cached. As of Jul 20, 2020 all mainstream browsers respect this.

Beware of intermediate caches though (proxy / CDN): If an intermediary has a nonzero minimum TTL, your response will be cached no matter what you do. See for example:

[Managing How Long Content Stays in an Edge Cache (Expiration)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html)

last line of the table (*Origin adds Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, and/or private directives to objects*). In this case, the only way to prevent caching is to set the TTL to 0 (and add the `Cache-Control: no-store` header of course).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on individual client's browser caching settings: IE has an option to "NEVER" check for new pages, it has the same effect on redirects.
And AFAIR IE's "Automatic" settings (default?) is not much better.

Answer (score 0):

**Firefox**

It should not be cached, per [bug 812167](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=812167)