# How can I avoid "Are you sure you want to send a form again?"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my app

user can access to the community page just like this
`http://example.com/communities?tag=lovely`

then if I try to go back to the previous page. I always get this message

```
Are you sure you want to send a form again
```

This only appears when it's accessed from Safari

How can I avoid that. I don't want user to see it every time when they go back.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :communities
```

Comment: So, you're going back to a page that was generated in response to your posted form. This might not be desirable in, say, online banking systems. That's why the browser asks you. "How can I avoid that?" - mm, don't go back to such pages? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks for a reply. So is this how it's supposed to be? when you had tag search system. would your application become the same way just like mine?

Comment: Instead of posting a form, you could replace a `window.location` by javascript, thus turning it into GET-request

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Could you please show me how to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to avoid this problem is to make your POST responses return a [redirect (HTTP 301 or 303)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764297/difference-between-http-redirect-codes) to a new page, which the browser then requests with GET. Going back should (though doesn't always) fetch the original form page, not the POST.

In Rails, this run-around often looks like this:

1. client GETs `/foos/new`
2. server returns HTML with `<FORM method='POST' action='/foos'>`
3. client POSTs `/foos` (with params)
4. server creates a new Foo with id 123
5. server returns redirect to `/foos/123`
6. client GETs `/foos/123`
7. server returns HTML for newly created Foo

Comment: Thanks for a reply. for now my output code is just like this `respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @communities }
  end`

Comment: Yeah, that sounds right. Odd that the boilerplate Rails code doesn't handle this already.

Comment: Looking at your question code again, maybe the problem is that you are using POST to fetch `/communities?tag=lovely` when you should be using GET. POST is for when you want to create or update data on the server; GET is for reading what's already there.

Comment: simply how can I fix this? should I add `get 'communities/tag=:tag' => 'communities#index', :via => :get, :as => :communities_tag`

Comment: I believe your problem is not with routing, but with the client code (HTML or JS) on the requesting page. Rails `resources :communities` should provide the right route to your `def index` method and pass you the `tag` parameter in the `params` array.

Comment: `def show` won't be matter here.  the url transition is just like this. A user is at example.com/communities then if he clicks particular tag, it takes him to example.com/communities?tag=lovely

Answer (score -1):

just add

`window.location.replace("about:blank");`