# One URL: Two Different Redirects

Tags: php, redirect, post, get, http-status-codes

I have a URL that once handled `GET` and `POST` requests. I want it to now only handle `POST` requests, and do a redirect for other requests. Based [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764297/difference-between-http-redirect-codes), it appears that I should use a [`303`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303) after processing a `POST` request, and a [`301`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) for other requests.

My code flow would look like this:

```
if ('POST' === filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD')) {
    // process post request

    // set http status code
    header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other');
} else {
    // set http status code
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
}
header('Location: /newurl.php');
```

Is this the proper user of the redirect codes? I want to make sure the 301 won't be cached by browsers when a `POST` request is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 303 redirect you must specify a redirect URI:

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other');
header('location: http://www.example.com/some-url/');
```

As a workaround for caching the 301 response, you can set the expiration date in the past. This way the client is encouraged to mark the response as expired immediately:

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Expires: Sat, 1 Feb 1997 06:00:00 GMT');
```

The 303 response should not be cached by any client that respects [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.4):

> The 303 response MUST NOT be cached, but the response to the second
>   (redirected) request might be cacheable.

Considering the above, you could change initial code snippet to something like this:

```
if ('POST' === filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD')) {
    // process post request

    // set http status code
    header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other');
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/newurl.php'); // FULL URI HERE
    exit;
}

// set http status code
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: http://www.example.com/other-page.php');
```

However, in your case a 307 redirect should be more appropriate. Although 307 is a temporary redirect and you will always redirect on any request that is not POST you can change this behavior in the future because as per RFC "*Since the redirection MAY be altered on occasion, the client SHOULD continue to use the Request-URI for future requests*". The second advantage is that: "*This response    is only cacheable if indicated by a Cache-Control or Expires header field.*"

> The requested resource resides temporarily under a different URI.
>   Since the redirection MAY be altered on occasion, the client SHOULD
>   continue to use the Request-URI for future requests.  This response
>   is only cacheable if indicated by a Cache-Control or Expires header
>   field.

See [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.8) sec. 10.3.8

Comment: Seems like using the 'Cache-Control' and 'Expires' headers defeats part of the utility of the 301 redirect. The answers in the question that I linked to allude to the browser caching based on the request type. Also, my code example specifies a URL in both cases, because it's outside of the `if/else` block.

Comment: " *Seems like using the 'Cache-Control' and 'Expires' headers defeats part of the utility of the 301 redirect.* ". Can you give more details about that do you mean with that statement ?

Comment: 301 redirects are supposed to be cached by the client in order to enhance the user experience. It's discussed in the SO question that I linked to. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764297/difference-between-http-redirect-codes

Comment: @Sonny Makes sense. See my updated answer (*at the end*) with an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Your redirect should be

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/newurl.php',true,301);
```

for 301 code, similar with 303 (so you don't need the last Location header). [See the manual on header](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.header.php).

Comment: This appears to be a comment about code style and not an answer to the question. (Also note that the spec requires an absolute URI for location)

Comment: Good point about absolute URI. And no, it's not a matter of code style. Doing what he did, as far as I remember, will always result in 302 (Found) redirect. My method is the one you need to use in order to have a proper redirect codes.

Comment: I used [this code](http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/24167607/test.phps) and got a `HTTP/1.1 303 See Other` response when I tested it with cURL.

Comment: The Wikipedia page actually gives an example with relative URLs, so I'm not sure why you mention having to use an absolute URI. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location#Relative_URL_example

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the additional arguments for the `header()` function. I will be using those.