# Why does Django's HTTPResponseRedirect use the same HTTP method for PUT but not POST?

Tags: python, django, http, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

I have a Django project where I'm using a view to handle different HTTP methods. The `POST` handled the creation of an object and then redirected to the same view as a `GET` (or so I thought), using Django's `redirect()` shortcut (`HTTPResponseRedirect`) to return the newly created object. This worked fine. I tried the same thing with a `PUT` but I fell into a redirect loop. After scratching my head for a while I stumbled across [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3024528/1086938) and then I inferred that since redirect doesn't handle the `POST` data, the request turns into a `GET`.

I confirmed this by watching the logs when I do the redirect from a `POST`:

```
[15/Dec/2014 00:47:43] "POST /client/151/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[15/Dec/2014 00:47:43] "GET /client/151/ HTTP/1.1" 200 395
```

However the `PUT` stays a `PUT` and throws me into a redirect loop until it errors out.

```
[14/Dec/2014 23:07:36] "PUT /api/asset/6779 HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[14/Dec/2014 23:07:37] "PUT /api/asset/6779/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[14/Dec/2014 23:07:37] "PUT /api/asset/6779 HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[14/Dec/2014 23:07:38] "PUT /api/asset/6779/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[14/Dec/2014 23:07:38] "PUT /api/asset/6779 HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[14/Dec/2014 23:07:39] "PUT /api/asset/6779/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[14/Dec/2014 23:07:39] "PUT /api/asset/6779 HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[14/Dec/2014 23:07:40] "PUT /api/asset/6779/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[14/Dec/2014 23:07:40] "PUT /api/asset/6779 HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[14/Dec/2014 23:07:41] "PUT /api/asset/6779/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[14/Dec/2014 23:07:41] "PUT /api/asset/6779 HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[14/Dec/2014 23:07:42] "PUT /api/asset/6779/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

Shouldn't the redirect use `GET`? I understand what's going on but not sure why? What gives?

**EDIT**

```
# urls.py
url(r'^$', views.put_vs_post_redirect),

# views.py
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def put_vs_post_redirect(request, asset_id):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return HTTPResponse('Get request')     
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        return redirect('/')
    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        return redirect('/')
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628831/apache-301-redirect-and-preserving-post-data

Comment: How are you making the user agent perform a PUT? A redirect to GET from a POST makes sense, because you can make a browser browse to a page using POST (form), but not by PUT. It seems you are writing an API. Why not just return the URI to the created object in a 200 OK response (or just document it is where you PUT it) and have the user agent act on that?

Also, you POST with a trailing slash and PUT without. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Anton great points. Thanks. Your workaround is acceptable but what i was trying to accomplish is, when the PUT is done I return the new object so I redirect to the GET which is designed to give me an object. At this point I have a workaround but I'm more interested in figuring out if this is Django's doing or if this is done at the HTTP level.

Comment: It's done at the HTTP level, specifically in the client implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is entirely dependent on the client, and not all clients handle redirects in the same way. You can find [a decent explanation of the redirect codes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4764297/359284) and [why a 301 should drop POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13628831/359284) on Stack Overflow.

When working with a `301` (and often a `302`) redirect, most browsers will discard `POST` data and make a `GET` request. This is mostly because browsers *have always done this*, and `POST` requests most commonly come from web forms, so it makes sense that the redirect results in a `GET`, allowing for the browser to display a different page without interfering. This is not the case for things like `PUT` or `PATCH` requests, as they cannot currently be sent by web forms and typically play by different rules.

If you are looking to maintain the `POST` data on a `302` redirect, you should consider [using a `307` redirect instead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection). A `307` request should maintain the request method, and the request body as a result.

If you are looking to maintain the `POST` data in a `301` redirect, there is currently [a draft for a `308` status code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7238) that would work like the `307`, but be permanent.

*You can* force the redirect to use a `GET` request with [a `303` redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303). It works very much like a `302`, but it enforces that the request method is always a `GET` request. It's often used in APIs for asynchronous tasks.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for the explanation and the proposed solution.