# Proper cache headers to ensure PHP pages are always re-fetched

Tags: php, apache, caching

After spending 2 days reading about cache headers, I'm still unsure what's the best combination to ensure that a PHP page with dynamic content will always be re-fetched from the server.

I believe a `Cache-Control: no-cache` header seems to be enough, and maybe an `Expires` header with a value in the past to ensure compatibility with HTTP 1.0 proxy caches.

---

### Pragma

`Pragma` is not specified as a response header:

> Note: because the meaning of "Pragma: no-cache as a response header field is not actually specified, it does not provide a reliable replacement for "Cache-Control: no-cache" in a response

The behavior of the `Pragma` header in the response is implementation-specific, and I believe it doesn't add much when the headers already include:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache 
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
```

`Pragma: no-cache` is non-standard and seems completely unnecessary.

---

### Cache-Control

The `Cache-Control` header accepts many values, so here is the breakdown I've got to:

- `no-cache` means to treat the resource as stale and re-validate (through `If-Modified-Since`/`If-None-Match`) on subsequent requests. It implies `max-age=0, must-revalidate`, so I don't need those headers. Some recent browsers even treat `no-cache` as `no-store`.
- `no-store` is mostly related to security, to prevent storing responses containing sensitive data in the computer. Not only I normally wouldn't need it, but it also seems completely redundant as the response is served with a `Cache-Control: no-cache` header (must be re-validated) and no means of validation (no `Last-Modified`/`ETag`), rendering the response unusable by any cache. Hence, it seems completely redundant.
- `proxy-revalidate` seems redundant due to the same reason above.
- `public`/`private` seem redundant as well, as the response is unusable by any cache mechanism.
- `pre-check=0, post-check=0` are IE-specific values, which I believe to be unnecessary as well.

---

### Context

I'm not using SSL/HTTPS, so the IE8 bugs which are said to appear with `Cache-Control: no-cache` don't apply to this question. I also don't care whether the browser uses a stored copy or re-fetches resources when pressing the back/forward buttons.

---

### Question

Are all my assumptions above correct? Anything I've overlooked? Or any possible improvements?

---

### References

- [What's the difference between Cache-Control: max-age=0 and no-cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1046966/1331430) - SO thread.
- [Caching on the Edge](http://www.slideshare.net/fabpot/caching-on-the-edge) - presentation.
- [rfc2616 - Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1, Section 14: Header Field Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your assumptions are correct. I've done a lot of projects involving dynamic data and we never needed anything more than `Cache-Control: no-cache` (a HTTP/1.1 header). Setting an `Expires:` date in the past is also good practice to cover HTTP/1.0 user agents.

That said, if you want to specifically inform requesting agents that the page is definitely distinct from the previous access, it might be worth sending an `Etag:` header which is time-based. That way, *any* previously fetched copy will have a different `Etag` and the agent will be aware that the copy now being sent is new. This will marginally increase request header size as the request will contain the previous `Etag` if any.

Comment: Are there such a thing as HTTP/1.0 user agents? I've looked around for a list but couldn't find anything. I'm assuming the IE <= 5.5 era. +1 for the feedback, I'll leave the question open a bit longer even though I'm rather positive that `Cache-Control: no-cache` should be enough.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073392/is-http-1-0-still-in-use) post. As of 2010, `wget` still used HTTP/1.0.