# Twisted Web Client HTTP Version

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web

If I am issuing an HTTP request using twisted.web.client.Agent how do I force the request to use HTTP 1.0? By default HTTP 1.1 is used.

Edit: The reason why I am interested in using HTTP 1.0 is because I wish to disable Chunked Transfer Encoding, and the most reliable way of doing this is by using HTTP 1.0.

Comment: Why the downvote? I searched the docs, web, and source code pretty thoroughly and I was not able to find an answer.

Comment: HTTP 1.1 was released in 1999. At the time, Netscape Navigator 4.0 was a current web browser.  Do you really need to support Netscape Navigator 3.0?

Comment: @Glyph No, I want to turn off Chunked Transfer Encoding, and the most reliable way of doing this is by using HTTP 1.0. And it is not like *nothing* uses HTTP 1.0 anymore, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073392/is-http-1-0-still-in-use) for instance.

Comment: But point taken, I will modify the original question to include this justification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `twisted.web.client.Agent`, you can’t without monkeypatching or something. Tracing through [the source](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/web/_newclient.py?rev=42679#L630), one of the things you’ll find is:

```
# In the future, having the protocol version be a parameter to this
# method would probably be good.  It would be nice if this method
# weren't limited to issueing HTTP/1.1 requests.
requestLines = []
requestLines.append(
    '%s %s HTTP/1.1\r\n' % (self.method, self.uri))
```

So it’s hardcoded. You might be able to get around that with some monkeypatching, but it’s not terribly easy.

---

But that doesn’t mean you’re out of luck; that applies only to `twisted.web.client.Agent`. If you can move away from using that class, it appears some old HTTP 1.0-only code is still around. In particular, if you use these classes/functions, it looks like you’ll be using HTTP 1.0:

- `HTTPPageGetter`
- `HTTPPageDownloader`
- `HTTPClientFactory`
- `HTTPDownloader`
- `getPage`
- `downloadPage`

But if you stray from those, I think you’ll end up using the new HTTP 1.1-only (for now) implementation.

Comment: I don't think that twisted.web.client.Agent uses HTTPClient. And even if it does, if you look at the server logs then a GET request from Agent gives you something like GET index.html HTTP/1.1. So it is definitely using HTTP 1.1 by default. Also by default twisted.web.http.protocol_version is "HTTP/1.1" (on line 129 of the source you linked to).

Comment: @Veered: Sorry, you must be looking at the old version of my answer.  I looked into it further and indeed, Twisted has two separate implementations of HTTP clients, one older HTTP 1.0 implementation and a new HTTP 1.1 implementation.  I think `Agent` will always use the 1.1 implementation, so if you want 1.0, you might have to use some of the older functions and classes. (Also, that `protocol_version = "HTTP/1.1"` is a red herring, since that variable is never used.)

Comment: Oh gotcha, thanks for the update! Since this is for personal use right now I just stuck with Agent and manually changed the source you linked to, and it works great!